HTML要素の内容を省略表示したい
HTMLで要素をまとめて(?)いる画像にある・・・のようなものはどうやったら実装できますか？
コードが長くなるのをまとめているのかなと思いますが、検索しても答えがヒットしないのでお力添えいただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。
例:


html を使って、Web ページを作っているのですか？何を使って、何を作っているのかを説明いただくと、回答がつきやすいと思います。

例示された画像は何を使って・どのように表示しているのかの説明もあると伝わりやすいと思います。合わせて、タイトルで「初心者」と書いても質問の説明にはならないので、何を聞きたいのかを端的に記したほうが回答が付きやすいと思います。

「できる」というのは、どうやったら中身を見れるのかということですか？　ご質問を [edit] して、ご質問の内容をより詳しく書いてみていただけないでしょうか。

左側に見える三角印(▶, ▼)は折り畳み要素を示しています ("アコーディオン"とも呼ばれてそう)
回転して開閉状態を示す小さな三角形は

右向き(▶)は閉じて(close)いて, 折り畳んでいる(折り畳まれている)状態
下向き(▼)は開いて(open)いて, 詳細が表示されている状態

操作は
三角印の位置 (あるいはラベルが含まれればラベル含んだ位置)で, クリック・タップで開閉可能
またはその位置でキータイプできるなら SPC でも開閉可能
参考: (developer.mozilla.org) <details>: 詳細折りたたみ要素
(以下はその例。スニペット実行で実行可能)


<details>
  <summary>Details</summary>
  この内容が見えるなら, 開いている状態
</details>



